# Yii: New DB connections when using CActiveRecord Cache

Tags: php, caching, model, yii

I'm using cache in `CActiveRecord` as:

```
$myoboject = ListModel::model()->cache(60)->findAll();
```

According to documentation it caches the result set for 60 seconds.

I would like to ask, will it open a new DB connection if another request will come within 60 second ? What I think it should not do like this, instead it should fetch the cached data.

I'm having this problem because I wanted to avoid the multiple db connection being opened by a script and I want to cache the data for 60 seconds, and after that it can be invalidated.

Am I on the right track ? is this a normal behaviour ? will anybody please let me know if there is something wrong ?

I have used both Memcache and Sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some research, [forum discussions](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/38720-using-cache-in-cactiverecord/page__gopid__186410#entry186410) and analyzing the CDConnection and CActiveRecord code, it is confirmed that it must open a new connection. So either we write our code to avoid this or wait for a feature. Till than we can use data caching by saving the data object into cache.